# Why does an infinite loop block a printf statement earlier in my C program?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, printf

This C program prints `Done`, then enters an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Done");
    while (1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, this code does *not* print `Done`. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to flush the buffer.  Usually console output doesn't flush until it receives a `'\n'`.

There's a little-used function for this, `fflush()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Done");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

That should print for you.

Answer (score 4):

stdout is buffered. It won't print until its flushed (e.g., but hitting a newline character).

You could just add a `'\n'` to your `printf` call:

```
printf("Done\n");
```

Or disable its buffing by calling

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `fflush(stdout);` after your `printf` statement. `stdout` is usually line-buffered by default.